# How to remove character limit and cropping text in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to remove character limit and cropping text in banner description.
I know in the file

```
      admin/controller/design/banner.php
```

is code:

```
  if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 1864)) {
        $this->error['name'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
 }
```

as you can see I modified it but still it doesn't work.

I really want it because I am using banner's description in slideshow.

Thank you

Comment: Are you any getting validation error or not getting in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change that php file limit `utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 100000000` and go to database find the table "yourprefix_banner_image_description" and change the "title" Field Type from varchar to text.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly all these validation rules resides in **database structure** itself - as all `VARCHAR` have defined their maximal length. If You want to extend/change the validation rules allowing the user to insert more text (characters) **do not forget to change the appropriate column definition as well**.

This means e.g. if the customer name is allowed to be at least 2 and maximally 100 characters but You'd like to allow the name to be 200 characters long, You'd need to change the appropriate column from `VARCHAR(100)` into `VARCHAR(200)`...